# PHP echo inline CSS background url

Tags: php, html, css

I am trying to echo some inline CSS using PHP using this:

```
echo '<div class="image" style="background:url("img/testimage.jpg");width:300px;height:232px;">';
echo '</div>';
```

But for some reason this is returning this:

```
<div class="image" testimage.jpg");width:300px;height:232px;"="" img="" style="background:url("></div>
```

This is within a WordPress environment, am I doing something obvious wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo '<div class="image" style="background:url(\'img/testimage.jpg\');width:300px;height:232px;">';
echo '</div>';
```

Answer (score 10):

Escape the quotes inside the url declaration properly:

```
echo '<div class="image" style="background:url(\'img/testimage.jpg\'); width:300px; height:232px;">';
                                    //         ^                  ^
```

Comment: @fightstarr20 yeah that subtle thing will mess it up. im glad this helped

Answer (score 2):

you can't run something like this (in HTML) correctly:

```
style="background:url("img/testimage.jpg");width:300px;height:232px;"
```

must merge between single and duple quotes or escape them:

```
style="background:url('img/testimage.jpg');width:300px;height:232px;"
```

solution:

```
echo "<div class='image' style='background:url(\"img/testimage.jpg\");width:300px;height:232px;'></div>";
```